# Add results from all rows into array

Tags: php, arrays

I am running a query that is returning several rows, each row contains a string of names separated by "|".

So I'm trying to break down the pipe separated results and build it all into a new array and I'm not having much success. It only seems to return results for one of the rows.

Here is the example code:

```
foreach($return['region'] as $result) {
  $namelist[] = explode("|", $result['name']);
}

// remove duplicates
$namelist = array_unique($namelist);

print_r($namelist);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Output of `vardump($return['region'])` (formatted for better readability):

```
array(14) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "8"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(153) "3018|3048|3050|3055|3058|3064|3066|3119|3138|3147|3163|3165|3179|3180"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "9"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(461) "3007|3018|3048|3050|3054|3057|3058|3060|3064|3066|3067|3068|3069|3073|3075|3077|3086|3087|3089|3096|3100|3117|3119|3126|3127|3130|3132|3138|3141|3147|3148|3152|3153|3163|3165|3167|3175|3179|3180|3184|3197|3199"
    }
    [2]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "10"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(483) "3007|3018|3048|3050|3054|3057|3058|3060|3064|3066|3067|3068|3069|3073|3075|3077|3086|3087|3089|3096|3100|3102|3117|3119|3126|3127|3130|3132|3138|3139|3141|3147|3148|3152|3153|3163|3165|3167|3175|3179|3180|3184|3197|3199"
    }
    [3]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "11"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(384) "3009|3018|3048|3050|3054|3055|3058|3060|3064|3066|3068|3069|3075|3077|3096|3117|3119|3126|3127|3132|3138|3141|3148|3152|3153|3158|3163|3165|3167|3172|3179|3180|3184|3197|3199"
    }
    [4]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "43"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(43) "3055|3068|3163|3165"
    }
    [5]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "41"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(54) "3055|3066|3073|3163|3165"
    }
    [6]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "42"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(43) "3007|3058|3163|3165"
    }
    [7]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "44"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(54) "3066|3068|3073|3163|3165"
    }
    [8]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "87"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [9]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "89"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [10]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "12" 
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(505) "3007|3018|3050|3054|3055|3057|3058|3060|3061|3064|3066|3067|3068|3069|3073|3074|3075|3077|3086|3087|3089|3096|3100|3102|3117|3119|3126|3127|3130|3132|3138|3139|3141|3147|3148|3153|3163|3164|3165|3167|3175|3179|3180|3184|3197|3199"
    }
    [11]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "13"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(505) "3007|3018|3048|3050|3054|3055|3057|3058|3060|3064|3066|3067|3068|3069|3074|3075|3077|3086|3087|3089|3096|3100|3102|3117|3119|3126|3127|3130|3132|3138|3139|3141|3147|3148|3153|3163|3164|3165|3167|3175|3176|3179|3180|3184|3197|3199"
    }
    [12]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "39"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(54) "3066|3068|3073|3163|3165"
    }
    [13]=> array(3) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "40"
        ["region"]=> string(2) "AU"
        ["name"]=> string(32) "3068|3073|3165"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `var_dump($return["region"])`?

Comment: It's not pretty, but I have added the output to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the result I am looking for. I feel like I could be doing this cleaner, but it works:

```
$qresult = $return['region'];
$qresult = array_filter($qresult);

$namelist = array();
  foreach($qresult as $result) {
    $namelist[] = $result['name'];
  }

$namelist = array_combine($namelist,$namelist);
$namelist = implode("|", $namelist);
$namelist = explode("|", $namelist);
$namelist = array_filter(array_unique($namelist));

print_r($namelist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if I am understanding your point.

```
foreach($return['region'] as $result) {
    $namelist[] = explode("|", $result['name']);

    // remove duplicates
    $namelist = array_unique($namelist);

    //print_r($namelist);
    printf("<pre>%s</pre>",print_r($namelist, true)) ;
}
```

Comment: This will print out the result for each row in the foreach loop, I am however trying to store the results from all rows into a variable I can use outside of this loop.